# Reading reports from django report_builder from another domain

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use the report_builder in django (http://django-report-builder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to read reports in a dashboard. I need to read it from another domain/django installation.

I already tried authenticating with a user who can access the reports from the other domain but i keep getting forwarded to the login page. When i try to fill in this page i get a csrf verification failed error. I can't disable the csrf verification because i'm not in control of that domain/django installation.

Do i need to implement something like http://www.django-rest-framework.org/ to handle authentication or am i missing something?

Comment: What is the mechanism for authentication ? On the server you are trying to access

Comment: You might be missing the {% csrf_token %} template tag in login form which give the csrf token for the application, if you are developing a restful webservice using django restframework or any other, we can skip the csrf verification using https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers in django.

Comment: The server i'm connecting to only have the default authentication build in django